# Is It ok to refresh admob programmatically when user clicks button?

Tags: android, request, admob, impressions

I have an application which has <kbd>prev</kbd> and <kbd>next</kbd> buttons, and I have written code so that when user clicks the <kbd>prev</kbd> or <kbd>next</kbd> button the admob request is generated.

Is it fair to use so? Or is it against the rules of admob? I have read somewhere that we must refresh it through code.

Answer (score 0):

This will not bring you more income as the payment amount depends on [Clicks per View]. More refreshing means more data traffic for the user. I always leave it with the default refresh rate.

Comment: Thats ok .. is it ok to do so as per admob norms to refresh like that??

Comment: AFAIK the automatic refresh that is set in the admob works in android, so I don't think you really need to refresh from code. The refresh from code is needed in WP7 development. Anyway, there will be no problem to refresh it from your code, I haven't found any constraints in the admob terms